# Differentiate access to the post based on a user's type

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm developing a blog and I need a differentiate access to the post based on a user's type. If the post is a draft only the staff user can read it, otherwise everyone can read it.

I've this code into a views.py:

```
geopost_filter = GeoPost.objects.filter(Q(draft=False) and Q(publishing_date__lte=timezone.now()))

def single_geopost(request, slug_post):
    if request.user.is_staff:
        geopost = get_object_or_404(GeoPost, slug_post=slug_post)
    else:
        geopost = get_object_or_404(geopost_filter, slug_post=slug_post)
    context = {
        "post": geopost,
        }
    template = 'geoblog/single_geopost.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

This function doesn't run because I can read the post whether I'm a staff member or a simple user. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Just need to change your geopost_filter query

geopost_filter = GeoPost.objects.filter(draft=False, publishing_date__lte=timezone.now())

def single_geopost(request, slug_post):
    if request.user.is_staff:
        geopost = get_object_or_404(GeoPost, slug_post=slug_post)
    else:
        geopost = get_object_or_404(geopost_filter, slug_post=slug_post)
    context = {
        "post": geopost,
        }
    template = 'geoblog/single_geopost.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: It's run! What is a problem in my filter? `geopost_filter = GeoPost.objects.filter(Q(draft=False) and Q(publishing_date__lte=timezone.now()))`

Comment: Your query doesn't need Q object, as it is used for complex queries. You query can include 'AND' with 'Q' Object. like this:- Q(draft=False) & Q(publishing_date__lte=timezone.now()). but for simplicity I used (draft=False, publishing_date__lte=timezone.now()) in the filter.